# Don't allow parent tree inside a another parent tree to be dragged - kendo drag and drop treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have one drag and drop tree:
[image]

The first image is a dragging node image. I dragged the 'furniture' parent node inside the 'storage' parent node. This dragged successfully(see second image).

I don't want to allow this to happen. How can I prevent it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution of not dnd of parent to inside other parent.

First get node.

```
sourceNode = this.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
```

then check if it's parent then does not allow to dnd inside parentnode otherwise dnd allow

```
if(item && !sourceNode.parentNode()){
sourceNode = this.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
}
```

see this example [here](http://jsbin.com/roreroxe/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so what you want is not allowing drag and drop between different TreeView while allowing drag and drop in a TreeView?

If I am not wrong, the solution is to check, in the drop event handler, if your destinationNode is a child of your current treeview. If not, you set the drop invalid.

here is a solution :

```
$("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
    dragAndDrop: true,
    dataSource: [/*..*/],
      drop: function (ev) {
                  var tree = $(this.root.context).data('kendoTreeView');
                  var dst = tree.dataItem(ev.destinationNode);
                   if (typeof dst === 'undefined') {
                      ev.setValid(false);
                   }
              }
  }
});
```

Comment: hello dievardump i want to does not allowing drag and drop parent node inside other parent node.

Comment: ok so here we have 3 parentNode. Furniture, Storage, Decor. Is it possible to send a child from Furniture to a Storage? Is it possible to transform a child from Furniture into a new parentNode?

Comment: yes child node allow to dnd to one parent to other parent but i want to does not allowing drag and drop parent node inside other parent node.

Comment: So listen to dragStart and if it's a parentNode, invalidate the dnd.

Comment: see if it's a parentnode then dont dnd but i doesn't want parent inside parent but i want to parent outside parent so what?.

Comment: Then you need to do it in the drop and test things. to end up with a "how can i see if it's a parentNode or a treeView". With the Manual and the codes Atanas and me provided you, you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the [dragstart](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#events-dragstart) event of the treeview and call e.preventDefault(). Here is how to prevent dragging of root nodes:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dragAndDrop: true,
  dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", items: [
      { text: "bar" }
    ] }
  ],
  dragstart: function(e) {
    if ($(e.sourceNode).parentsUntil(".k-treeview", ".k-item").length == 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: hello i added dragstart event in my kendotreeview code.but now not allow to parent node drag and drop. it's only allow to child node dnd.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you **do not want to drag any parent node** this code I found and use (from Telerik forums)

```
$(".k-treeview").data("kendoTreeView").bind("dragstart", function (e) {
    if ($(e.sourceNode).parentsUntil(".k-treeview", ".k-item").length == 0) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually that code I pasted won't allow you to change the sort order of any parent,  thus it works for specific business use case.